# android.os.Parcel.createExceptionOrNull Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-11

I am getting this exception on android 11 `Samsung` device.

This is the stack trace:

```
        at android.os.Parcel.createExceptionOrNull(Parcel.java:2389)
        at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:2369)
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2352)
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2294)
        at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub$Proxy.getHistoricalProcessExitReasons(IActivityManager.java:11260)
        at android.app.ActivityManager.getHistoricalProcessExitReasons(ActivityManager.java:4231)
        at androidx.work.impl.utils.ForceStopRunnable.isForceStopped(ForceStopRunnable.java:171)
        at androidx.work.impl.utils.ForceStopRunnable.forceStopRunnable(ForceStopRunnable.java:210)
        at androidx.work.impl.utils.ForceStopRunnable.run(ForceStopRunnable.java:108)
        at androidx.work.impl.utils.SerialExecutor$Task.run(SerialExecutor.java:91)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
```

can anyone help me in getting this issue resolved.

Comment: Do you get the same exception in the debug mode?

Comment: Provide some code please. This could be anything...